# Android fragment transactions - do they restore state of all objects or just views?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to know exactly what is restored by the Android system when a fragment is restored.  Is it only the rootView that is being created in onCreateView() or is it all objects in the fragment class?

per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#beginTransaction()) we know that a fragment manager will automatically restore state of a fragment ? but is this only view state?

> Note: A fragment transaction can only be created/committed prior to an activity saving its state. If you try to commit a transaction after Activity.onSaveInstanceState() (and prior to a following Activity.onStart or Activity.onResume(), you will get an error. **This is because the framework takes care of saving your current fragments in the state, and if changes are made after the state is saved then they will be lost**.

do i have to use

```
saveFragmentInstanceState(Fragment f)
```

if i want to save my non view objects ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save anything in particular you should override onSaveInstanceState() like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("TAG_OF_YOUR_CHOICE", yourIntVariable); //This is to save an int
}
```

For more information on what the default method does, [read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)).